# how to push data from one viewController to another without using Segues

Tags: xcode, viewcontroller

i have two view controllers TestViewController and SecondViewController.
i also have corresponding views TestView and SecondView corresponding to them.

please guide me with the steps to push data from one view Controller to another without using Segues.

Comment: why won´t u use segues as  Adi Azarya descibes?

Answer (score 0):

you can use  [Segues](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/UsingSegues.html) it is very easy to work with. You can use method inside your objective-c code:
for example:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    // Make sure your segue name in storyboard is the same as this line
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"YOUR_SEGUE_NAME_HERE"])
    {
        // Get reference to the destination view controller
        YourViewController *vc = [segue destinationViewController];

       // Pass any objects to the view controller here, like...
        [vc setMyObjectHere:object];
    }
}
```

In the link above you have all the explanation how to it... :) hope it helps.